# Data receiving problem in python socket server(tcp)

Tags: python-3.x

I am working in a python project and have made a python server and client using socket module. But I am facing a casual problem that the server is not receiving data from the client. Code is given below:

*Server*

```
import socket
from colorama import Fore

ip = input(f"{Fore.GREEN}Enter your ip addr\n{Fore.YELLOW}!\t$ ")
print(Fore.BLUE, 'The server is running on port number 8080')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost',8080))
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(Fore.RED, 'connection ready')
while True:
    cmd = input("Enter your cmd>>")
    if cmd == "":
        pass
    else:
        conn.sendall(cmd.encode('utf-8'))
        data = b""
        while True:
            resp = conn.recv(1024)
            if not resp:
                break
            data+= resp

        print(Fore.GREEN, data.decode())
```

*client*

```
import socket, os
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 8080))

while True:
    SerData = s.recv(1024).decode()
    CliData = os.popen(SerData)
    CliData = CliData.buffer.read()
    s.sendall(CliData)
```

Comment: you are connecting to localhost on client side, replace localhost with ip of your server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to run commands from the server onto the client machine and output the results of the client onto the server. While statement in the else is not required and that is what was causing the data to not print, I handled some encoding and decoding in both client and server.

Server.py

```
import socket
from colorama import Fore

ip = input(f"{Fore.GREEN}Enter your ip addr\n{Fore.YELLOW}!\t$ ")
print(Fore.BLUE, 'The server is running on port number 8080')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',8080))
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(Fore.RED, 'connection ready')
while True:
    cmd = input("Enter your cmd>>")
    if cmd == "":
        pass
    else:
        conn.sendall(cmd.encode('utf-8'))
        data = ""
        
        resp = conn.recv(1024)
        if not resp:
            break
        data+= str(resp, 'utf-8')

    print(Fore.GREEN, data)
```

client.py

```
import socket, os
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8080))

while True:
    SerData = s.recv(1024).decode()
    CliData = os.popen(SerData)
    CliData = CliData.buffer.read()
    CliData = str(CliData, "utf-8")
    s.sendall(str.encode(CliData))
```

Comment: still I have got  the same problem

Comment: there was an indentation problem, try the updated answer